# Can I say ' My pc having some faults, I returned it to the company.'

Tags: sentence-construction, absolute-clauses

Can I say:

> My pc having had some problems, I returned it to the manufacturer.

Instead of:

> As my pc had some problems, I returned....''

Similarly:

> He not coming, I won't go there.

If they are possible, please give me more examples of this kind.

Comment: The first sentence is good, but uses several tenses. You only need "my pc had some problems" or "my pc was having some problems"

Comment: Both your examples are *possible*, but idiomatically they're both extremely unlikely. Unfortunately I don't know offhand how to describe the contexts where ***participle clauses** (which [give information about condition, reason, result or time](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses)) work well, and where they don't.

Comment: Some of them experiencing any difficunties, we'll change the timetable.

Comment: Is the sentence above possible?

Comment: I disagree that the first sentence is possible (please argue if you think I'm wrong). In the first sentence, you are talking about two different things: "the pc that had problems" and "**I** returning it" however, you only use one verb ("returned"). You could correct it by making it a compound sentence ("My pc had some problems so I returned it to the manufacturer.") of by making "pc" the subject of the main verb ("My pc, having had some problems, had to be returned to the manufacturer.")

Comment: A minor correction: acronyms and initialisms should always be capitalized: "My PC", not "My pc".

Comment: @G-Cam The first sentence is grammatically acceptable: that first piece is an [absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) construction. But absolutes are rare, and in most contexts pompous.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed, but it is rather literary - few people would use that construction (an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction)) in ordinary speech.

The second is very unlikely, for several reasons. First, the literary tone of the absolute construction doesn't match the colloquial "won't". Secondly, the construction is usually used only in narrative, so it is unlikely to be used in the present (unless it is a present tense narrative). Thirdly, especially with a "not" in the absolute clause, I would expect the main clause to refer to it in some way. Eg "He not coming, I went on my own". Note also that "He not coming" would mean something like "Because he did not come (i.e. arrive)": it doesn't mean "Because he was not coming (i.e. accompanying me)".

Comment: Shouldn't it be "He wasn't coming, I went on my own."?

Comment: @SovereignSun: Shouldn't _what_ be that? What you have quoted there is a comma-splice: two sentences joined by a comma. People do say that sort of thing, but the semantic relationship between the two is not clear, so it is frowned on in writing. "He not coming, I went on my own" is perfectly grammatical and meaningful, but unlikely to occur outside a written narrative.

Comment: So if I rephrase it to: "He wasn't coming so I went on my own." It's the same as "He not coming, I went on my own"?

Comment: @SovereignSun, yes, except that the paraphrase could have a different tense "He didn't come so I went on my own". Your version implies that I somehow found out beforehand that he was not planning to come, whereas the simple past simply says that he didn't come without any implication about my knowledge. The absolute clause is similarly unspecific.